# Prove a real valued function is increasing

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Prove $$-\frac{x(1-x^c)\ln x}{(1-x)^2}$$
 $c>0$ is an increasing function on $[0,1]$.

I have a relatively cumbersome proof sketched below. I would like to see other ideas, particularly simpler ones.

---

Define $$g(x,c) = -\frac{x(1-x^c)\ln x}{c(1-x)^2}.$$ Then 
$$\frac{g(x,c_2)}{g(x,c_1)}=\frac{c_1(1-x^{c_2})}{c_2(1-x^{c_1})},$$
$0\le c_1<c2$ is increasing for $x\in[0,1]$. Thus, if $g(x,c_1)$ increases then $g(x,c_2)$ also increases.

Take $c_1=0$, $g(x,0)=\frac{x(\ln x)^2}{(1-x)^2}$. We can show $g(x,0)$ is increasing in $x$ by substituting $x = e^{-2t}$. Therefore, $g(x,c)$ is increasing in $x$ for $c>0$.

Comment: Could you give at least a high-level sketch of the methods your "cumbersome proof" uses? Otherwise it is hard for someone to know whether his ideas are any simpler.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: I am a little afraid that doing so would  interfere with other people's exploration. It is till nice even if others come up with similar ideas.

Comment: x @Hansen: I'm afraid _not_ doing so will significantly reduce people's willingness to spend time helping you.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: I have put up my proof sketch. Does it help?

Comment: Why do you divide by $c$ in the definition of $g$? In any case, I don't think your sketch works because $g(x,0)$ has $0$ in the numerator, not $x(\log x)^2$ as you write. Remember $x^0=1$, so $1-x^c=0$ when $c=0$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Your second assertion regarding $g(x,0)$ is wrong. But ironically, it answers your first question.

Comment: Are you proposing to cancel the 0?? That's not valid.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Do you think $\lim\limits_{c\searrow 0}\frac{1-x^c}{c}$ exits?

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Do you agree now?

Answer (score 0):

$$-\frac{x(1-x^c)\ln x}{(1-x)^2} \;\; = \;\; x \cdot (x^c - 1) \cdot \ln x \cdot \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$$

Note that this is a product of $4$ functions, each of which is increasing on the *open* interval defined by $0 < x < 1.$

**NOTE:** This is incorrect reasoning, as explained in the comments. I'll leave it up so that others can see why the kind of simplistic approach I used doesn't work, and in case I think of something reasonably simple that does work.

Comment: Note the second and third functions in your RHS expression are negative. By your logic, $(1-x)(1-x)$ would have been increasing in $(0,1)$.

Comment: The product of the two functions in the middle however is decreasing. So maybe there's a little more to that?

Comment: @Hansen and Macavity: You're correct, I jumped the gun too quickly and (to continue the analogy) I got shot. It's the SUM of increasing functions that's increasing. I guess if the functions are all positive valued, their product would be increasing, but they're not all positive valued here. A counterexample even simpler than $(1-x)(1-x)$ is $x \cdot x.$ The function $f(x) = x$ is increasing on the interval $(\infty, \infty),$ but the product $f(x)\cdot f(x) = x^2$ is definitely not increasing on $(-\infty,\infty).$